# Emitting events from class

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, eventemitter

Is it possible to emit events from the class?

```
class MyEvent extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this.options = options;
    this.execute();
  }

  execute() {
    // do something;
    this.emit("close"); // Pass here to the instance.
  }
}
```

Then:

```
const myEvent = MyEvent({});
myEvent.on("close", (data) => {
  // do something here.
});
```

Currently the close event is not being called from the class. But here => https://coligo.io/nodejs-event-emitter/ since to work.

Comment: A constructor should never `execute` anything. Its only purpose is to initialise the instance.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you call `execute` in the constructor. It gets called but your event handler is attached after the object is constructed. Try calling `myEvent.execute()` after you attach the event handler to see if it gets called.

Comment: Nice one! Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to avoid calling execute in the event?

Comment: You mean in the constructor? You should not emit any events from there since they cannot be handled.